# Laravel + Postgres - Retornar 't' ou 'f' no lugar de true ou false

Tags: laravel, postgresql, querybuilder

Olá,

Ao realizar uma consulta em um campo `booleano` no Postgres nós temos um retorno de `'t'` ou `'f'`.

Estou tendo um problema ao tentar migrar uma API feita em `Codeigniter` para uma API que estou desenvolvendo em `Laravel 5.7`. O problema é que o `Codeigniter` retorna `'t'` ou `'f'` nas consultas, e o `Laravel` retorna `true` ou `false`. Eu preciso deixar o retorno do `Laravel` igual ao do `Codeigniter`, pois não é viável para mim mexer no Front-End que consome essa API.

Seria ideal para mim se fosse possível configurar isso em apenas um lugar da minha aplicação, sem precisar alterar todas as queries que estou realizando. Também é importante pontuar que não estou utilizando o `Eloquent`, estou utilizando o `Query Builder` do `Laravel`

Exemplo de retorno do `Codeigniter` [Linha 5]

```
{
  "id": "5794",
  "valor_frete": 19.8,
  "prazo_entrega": 6,
  "exibe_prazoentrega": "t",
  "destino": "RJ - Rio de Janeiro - Capital",
  "transportadora": "Correios",
  "nome": "PAC - Encomenda Normal",
  "texto": "PAC - Encomenda Normal",
  "frete_gratis": "Frete Grátis",
  "valor_frete_original": 19.8
},
```

Exemplo de retorno do `Laravel` [Linha 7]

```
{
  "id": 5794,
  "nome": "PAC - Encomenda Normal",
  "texto": "PAC - Encomenda Normal",
  "destino": "RJ - Rio de Janeiro - Capital",
  "transportadora": "Correios",
  "exibe_prazoentrega": true,
  "valor_frete": 19.8,
  "prazo_entrega": 6,
  "valor_frete_original": 19.8
},
```

Obrigado.

Comment: como que está no banco de dados ? essa mesma linha ?

Comment: Se tem que criar o modificador de acesso mesmo ou até um append são coisas a pensar. No CodeIngniter como o cara fez?

Comment: No Codeigniter ele vem por default

Comment: Desculpa Jhonny como? se pode mostrar isso na sua pergunta? porque se for um dado `char` por exemplo no Laravel também deveria, talvez a gente precisa entender como está sendo gravado na base se tem como demonstrar?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode adicionar isso ao Model

```
public function getExibePrazoentregaAttribute($value)
{
    return $value?'t':'f';
}
```

Ou seja, sempre que você recuperar o campo **exibe_prazoentrega**, ele vai entrar em **getExibePrazoentregaAttribute** e verificar, se for **true**, vai retornar **t** se não retorna o **f**

Qualquer dúvida edita seu post com o seu Model que eu atualizo aqui.

Comment: Eu tinha pensado nisso, mas eu teria que fazer isso algumas centenas de vezes, a API é gigante HEHE

Comment: Bom, ae você pode faze rum script que adiciona essas linhas a todos os seus Models.

Comment: Amanhã quando eu for trabalhar eu vejo isso e te aviso o resultado.